# How to use Left join with or condition on two fields?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

```
invoiceData = from x in context.PdtDeliveryTables 
    join pt in context.DiagramNoTables on x.DiagramID equals pt.DiagramID
    join mt in context.MaterialTables on pt.MaterialID equals mt.MaterialID into t from ct in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join odr in context.OrderTables on x.OrderID equals odr.OrderID into sr
    from d in sr.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where (pt.CustomerID == customerID) && (x.DeliveryDate >= (startDate ?? DateTime.MinValue) && x.DeliveryDate <= (endDate ?? DateTime.MaxValue))
    orderby x.DeliveryDate  ascending
    select new InvoiceTable
        {    
        };
```

I need this left join condition to be replaced on an OR condition:

```
join odr in context.OrderTables on x.OrderID equals odr.OrderID into sr
from d in sr.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

as like to:

```
join odr in context.OrderTables on x.OrderID equals 
    x => x.OrderID !=0 
        ? x.OrderNo
        : x.DeliveryNo 
into sr from d in sr.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

- below is the changed query but I still get Time out exception
- Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

  ```
              invoiceData = from x in context.PdtDeliveryTables
                           join pt in context.DiagramNoTables on x.DiagramID equals pt.DiagramID
                           join mt in context.MaterialTables on pt.MaterialID equals mt.MaterialID into t from ct in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           from d in context.OrderTables.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           where (x.OrderID != 0 && x.OrderID == d.OrderID) || (x.OrderID == 0 && x.DeliveryNo == d.OrderNo)
                           where (pt.CustomerID == customerID) && (x.DeliveryDate >= (startDate ?? DateTime.MinValue) && x.DeliveryDate <= (endDate ?? DateTime.MaxValue))
                           orderby x.DeliveryDate  ascending
             select new InvoiceTable
             {
                  OrderID = x.OrderID,
                  OrderNo = x.OrderID != 0 ? d.OrderNo : x.DeliveryNo,
                  DiagramNo = pt.DiagramNo,
                  ProductName = pt.ProductName,
                  MaterialName = ct.MaterialName,
                  Quantity = x.DeliveryQty,
                  OrderDate = x.DeliveryDate,
                  InvoiceDate = d.InvoiceDate,
                  UnitPrice = d.UnitPrice != null ? d.UnitPrice : pt.SellingPrice,
                  Amount = d.UnitPrice != null ? d.UnitPrice * x.DeliveryQty : pt.SellingPrice * x.DeliveryQty,
                  Printable = true
              };                       
          }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I removed join syntax between x (PdtDeliveryTables) and odr (OrderTables), and changed it on where expression:

```
invoiceData = 
    from x in context.PdtDeliveryTables 
    from odr in context.OrderTables.DefaultIfEmpty() 
    where (odr.OrderID != 0 && x.OrderID == x.OrderNo) 
          || x.OrderID == x.DeliveryNo)
    join pt in context.DiagramNoTables on x.DiagramID equals pt.DiagramID
    join mt in context.MaterialTables on pt.MaterialID equals mt.MaterialID 
    into t 
    from ct in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where (pt.CustomerID == customerID) 
           && (x.DeliveryDate >= (startDate ?? DateTime.MinValue) 
               && x.DeliveryDate <= (endDate ?? DateTime.MaxValue))
    orderby x.DeliveryDate  ascending
    select new InvoiceTable
        {    
        };
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the query is going to exception , I think its going on infinate time out exeception.

Comment: I have given the changed query in the above updated code but I get time out exception.

Comment: Try limit query results, to be shure that query is valid, for example add First() at the end.